# Issue in Azure Auto-Failover Group with Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, automatic-failover

Am working on the Azure SQL with Auto-Failover Group, for this I created one SQL Server along with one database and I created another copy of database in another SQL Server which is created with the help of Geo-Replication in other region. For that, I created one failover group and working fine. But while working with this, some doubts were raised to me like:

1. My Primary region like East US has been collapses due unexpected disaster occurs, then what about my SQL Database and all my failover groups condition. Is it possible to recover them?
2. If I delete primary SQL Database, then what happen to my fail over group?
3. If I delete my primary SQL server, then is it my fail over group work finely?

For doing the above, I followed the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview#auto-failover-group-capabilities)

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the primary the failover group is removed and the geo-replication is removed too. The secondary database will remain with no geo-replication configured. I just tested this on Azure portal.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Alberto. I know that already, am getting the same but I need to recovery even the above issues mentioned in the question done